# Tar big files in different directories

Tags: shell-script, tar, compression

I have ~20 files, each about 10 GB in size, in different folders that I need to compress into a single tar. It is not practical to copy them all to one location. More precisely, the files are organized something like this:

index1_index2/subfolder/bigfile.dat

Here index1 and index2 each vary over a few values.

What is a practical way to get a single tarball containing all these files, say with bash or something?

Comment: Do you want the archive members to be `index1_index2/subfolder/bigfile.dat`, or `subfolder/bigfile.dat`, or `bigfile.dat`?

Comment: Is the filename always `bigfile.dat`? Are there other files that are bigger? I would try it with `find options | xargs tar czf bigtar`. The options depend on your answer.

Comment: Yes it is always the same filename. I didn't realize you could pipe things into tar, that makes things easier

Comment: Piping as suggested by @ott would result in multiple invocations of `tar`, which would create one file containing only as many files as the last time `tar` was run.  Perhaps not what was anticipated.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Piping to `xargs` results in exact one invocation of `tar`. `tar c` creates a new archive or overwrites an existing one, no matter what happended on an earlier run. Have you overlooked that `xargs`?

Answer (score 4):

If they are on the same filesystem, you could hard-link those to a common directory and tar *that* directory.

Alternatively, if you are using GNU tar, you could (with a little more flexibility) soft-link those to a common directory and using its `-h` option, tar the files which the soft-links point to.

The manual page for the [latter shows](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC140):

> **`-h`**, **`--dereference`**
>   follow symlinks; archive and dump the files they point to

[FreeBSD tar](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tar%281%29) supports equivalent options, but names them like `pax` (see below).

There is of course no POSIX tar to use for comparison.  If you can use [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html), it has a similar `-L` option:

> **`-L`**
>   If a symbolic link referencing a file of type directory is specified on the command line or encountered during the traversal of a file hierarchy, `pax` shall archive the file hierarchy rooted in the file referenced by the link, using the name of the link as the root of the file hierarchy. Otherwise, if a symbolic link referencing a file of any other file type which `pax` can normally archive is specified on the command line or encountered during the traversal of a file hierarchy, `pax` shall archive the file referenced by the link, using the name of the link. The default behavior, when neither **`-H`** or **`-L`** are specified, shall be to archive the symbolic link itself.

Whether hard-linking, or soft-linking, the result is that you do not have to move your existing files.  Hard-linking *changes* the `ctime` (timestamp) of your files, while soft-linking does not.  But soft-linking (though it reduces the necessity of being on the same filesystem) is not universally supported by tar implementations using identical options.

OP's original statement appeared to indicate that the reason why it was inconvenient to put all files together in one directory was because of some limitation by the application which generates them.  Clarification makes it apparent that the problem is that they all have the same filename.  While linking into one directory (and for instance encoding their original *directory name* into the common location) is certainly doable, there are other options for simply collecting the files into a single archive, retaining their existing directory names.  One drawback to doing this is that it limits the ability to restore  into arbitrary locations.  However: the simplest way of passing some ~20 names to tar would be on the command-line, e.g.,

```
`tar czf myoutput.tar.gz $(find . -type f -name bigfile.dat)`
```

For only 20 files that is not likely to be a problem with command-line length.  If it were a large number of files (or very long pathnames), that would make it harder, since `tar` implementations as a rule lack the ability to pass a list of pathnames other than as separate command-line parameters (see [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/tar-1.html) for instance).  For those, one might try to work around the limitation by creating an archive in steps — but then that would not work with compression.  Some implementations provide options for reading a list of filenames from a file. The [GNU tar `-T`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC107) (also FreeBSD) option does this.  Other programs may provide a third alternative, reading the list of filenames from the standard input (as done by [pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html), which was influenced by [cpio](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/cpio-1.html#scrolltoc)), but generally tar does not: it may read the file *content* from standard input.

Comment: `pax` *is* `tar` *and* `cpio` *(at least - most `pax`s will also do `zip` and so on, but `tar` is the default archive format)*.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but depending on the system, OP may not even have `pax` installed.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is:

```
tar cfz bigtar.tar.gz /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 ... /path/to/file20
```

If there are matchable similarities between the target files, you could use `find` to create the files list and GNU `tar`'s `-T` (`--files-from`).

e.g. if they're all .mp4 files:

```
find /path -type -f -iname '*.mp4' | tar cf bigtar.tar -T -
```

Otherwise, if there's no easy pattern for selecting your filenames, you could use find to create an initial list in a tmpfile, edit that manually to remove filenames you don't want to include in the tar, and then use the edited tmpfile's name with tar's `-T` option.